# JSON UserData format for BaaS Kinvey SignupUser

Tags: json, delphi, c++builder, kinvey, mbaas

Using [`TBackEndUsers`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/REST.Backend.ServiceComponents.TBackendUsers) mBaaS component, in order to populate the **_push** column of new Kinvey user, I have to pass JSONObject **UserData** to the procedure:

```cpp
BackendUsers1->Users->SignupUser(AUserName, AUserData, AUserData, ACreatedObject);
```

Here is the piece of json requested:

```json
{
  "_push" : 
  {
    "_devicetokens": [
      "ffcde6a5918106507a460d9709462f5ba37f70aa76d64fa21a4bfd.........."
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the wrong piece of json that I obtained with the source code below:

```json
{
  "_push" : 
  {
    "_devicetokens" : "[\"ffcde6a5918106507a460d9709462f5ba37f70aa76d64fa21a4bfd..........\"]"
  }
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

```cpp
#define TOKENS "ffcde6a5918106507a460d9709462f5ba37f70aa76d64fa21a4bfd.........."

void __fastcall TMainForm::CreateUserButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
TBackendEntityValue ACreatedObject;
TJSONObject *JSONObject, *JSONPush;
TJSONPair *Pair, *Pair2;
TJSONArray *Array;
  JSONObject = new TJSONObject;
  Pair = new TJSONPair("first_name", FirstNameEdit->Text);
  JSONObject->AddPair(Pair);
  Pair = new TJSONPair("last_name", LastNameEdit->Text);
  JSONObject->AddPair(Pair);
  Pair = new TJSONPair("email", EMailEdit->Text);
  JSONObject->AddPair(Pair);
  Array = new TJSONArray;
  Array->Add((String) TOKENS);
  Pair2 = new TJSONPair("_devicetokens", Array->ToString());
  JSONPush = new TJSONObject(Pair2);
  Pair = new TJSONPair("_push", JSONPush);
  JSONObject->AddPair(Pair);    
  BackendUsers1->Users->SignupUser(UserIdEdit->Text, PasswordEdit->Text, JSONObject, ACreatedObject);    
  delete JSONObject;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You've explicitly asked to produce a string from that array when you were creating `Pair2` in `TJSONPair("_devicetokens", Array->ToString());`. You've certainly wanted to write just `TJSONPair("_devicetokens", Array);`.

Comment: Thank you TLama, you are right.
The problem is solved!